# HTML input pattern that consists of 4 numbers and 2 letters at the end

Tags: html, forms, validation

Ive looked around for different validation patterns but didnt find any good examples that would help me create something like that. For example **"5676AB"**.
Needs to have **4 numbers at the beginning, followed by 2 characters** (can be uppercase and also lowercase).

If anyone would help me I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = '5676AB';
console.log(str.match(/^[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}/));
```

Comment: Accepted this answer since it was the first one and they all are the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean patter attribute of input? Try this `pattern="[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{2}"`

Answer (score 1):

With just HTML you can validate input field  with `require` and `pattern` attributes.
Without `require` you will be able to submit an empty field

See the code snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
  Input field: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}" placeholder="4 digits, 2 letters: 1234AB" required />
  <input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```